# Error de herencia C#

Tags: c#

Buen día,

Una vez más apelo a su ayuda. Estoy realizando un ejercicio de la universidad, este consiste en utilizar los metodos de ordenamiento Shell, Burbuja, Insercion y Seleccion con 10 numeros. La idea del programa es que el usuario elija 1 de las 4 opciones para ordenar esos 10 numeros que el debe ingresar. Cree una matriz para guardar cada uno de los 10 numeros ingresados.  Utilice herencia, ya que al crear metodos para cargar numero, mostrar numero y guardar el ordenamiento. Esta informacion se repetia. El inconveniente que tengo es que al momento de instanciar las clases en la clase program, estas muestran error. Al igual que al querer utilizar la matriz en las distintas clases.

```
internal class Metodos
    {
        private int[] matriz;
        private int numero;

        public Metodos(int[] matriz, int numero)
        {
            this.matriz = new int[10];
            this.numero = 0;
        }
        public int getNumero()
        {
            return numero;
        }
        public void setNumero(int numero)`introducir el código aquí`
        {
            this.numero = numero;
        }

static void Main(string[] args)
        {

        Menu:
            Console.WriteLine(" ************************************************************");
            Console.WriteLine(" |      BIENVENIDOS AL PROGRAMA DE ORDENAMIENTO NUMERICO    |");
            Console.WriteLine(" |                                                          |");
            Console.WriteLine(" | Favor seleccione la opcion que requiera                  |");
            Console.WriteLine(" |                                                          |" +
                            "\n | 1. - Método Shell.                                       |" +
                            "\n | 2. - Método Burbuja.                                     |" +
                            "\n | 3. - Método Insercion.                                   |" +
                            "\n | 4. - Método Selección.                                   |" +
                            "\n | 5. - Salir.                                              |" +
                            "\n |                                                          |");
            Console.WriteLine(" ************************************************************");

            //INSTANCIAMIENTO DE LAS CLASES.

            Metodos metodo = new Metodos(1, 0);
            Burbuja burbuja = new Burbuja(1, 0);
            Insercion insercion = new Insercion(5, 0);
            Seleccion seleccion = new Seleccion(1, 0);
            Shell shell = new Shell(1, 0);
```

[Imagen del erro de la instanciacion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0sVL0.png)

[image: La segunda es el error que da el cada metodo de ordenamiento.]

Comment: Y tu pregunta es?

Comment: Ordenar_shell() dentro de que clase está?

Comment: Mi pregunta es, Como soluciono ese error que genera la matriz?

Comment: Yussef, Los metodos de ordenamiento se encuentran cada uno en su respectivas clases. Burbujas, insercion, shell y seleccion. Estas clase serian las clases hijas. Por otra parte, cree una clase llamada Metodos, que seria la clase padre y que lleva metodos que piden los numeros, otro para mostrar mostrar los numeros ingresados y un metodo mas para guardar los numeros ordenado en un archivo txt.

Comment: @jeisonmaestre Creo que entiendo. Entonces debes cambiar private int matriz[] por protected int matriz[]

Comment: Otra cosa, cuando respondas a alguien usa la @ de prefijo. Así salta una alerta, de pura suerte vi que me habías respondido

Comment: @Yussef, Gracias por la respuesta. Una molestia más, al momento de instanciar en la clase program. Este me pide los parametros de cada clase, y no he logrado colocar el parametro correcto, ya que en la clase padre que es metodos, coloque como parametro la matriz. Si miras en el codigo de arriba, te daras cuenta que en el instanciamiento de clases debo colocar los parametros.

Comment: @Yussef, gracias por tu respuesta. Me sirvio muchisimo. Una vez más, quedo agradecido.